# Google Home or Google Assistant Home Control behavior for long inactivity by end user

Tags: keycloak, actions-on-google

We have developed a Google Home Action integrating it with Keycloak OAuth and Custom Webhook The OAuth access token from Keycloak has a validity of 15 days

But after a long time of inactivity (1-2 months approx), the Testing Link was disabled and the Google Assistant was replying with the message '**{Action Name} is unavailable right now**' for all Smart Home Action voice commands like 'Sync my devices'

We have also enabled Testing in the deep link URL for the action test after this

But even after the Test was enabled, it still gave the same error message for all the voice commands.

**What is the expected implementation change to be done either from the Webhook or Google Home Action configuration side to handle such cases as the Google Home App is not asking the user for relinking the Action if the access token gets expired in the backend?**

The Keycloak URL and access details are configured in Google Action and the redirections to login and handling token are done by Google itself. So it is not in our control to get a new token without relinking the Google Home.

**Relinking on Google Home is the only option here or should I increase the Keycloak token validity?**

***P.S.*** - Do not close this ticket if a satisfying answer is not received by me. My previous ticket was closed without a proper answer and I had to raise this question again.

Answer (score 0):

The expectation is when an access token expires, Google sends a request to your token exchange endpoint to exchange a refresh token for a new access token.

Check out the [Smart Home OAuth docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/implement-oauth#exchange_refresh_tokens_for_access_tokens) to make sure that you're endpoint is providing the exchange refresh token info to get access tokens.  Below is an example of what your endpoint should return.

```
{
"token_type": "Bearer",
"access_token": "ACCESS_TOKEN",
"expires_in": SECONDS_TO_EXPIRATION
}
```

For more information on using tokens, I recommend checking out [Google Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking), section ["Working with tokens"](https://developers.google.com/identity/account-linking#working_with_tokens)

Comment: All the fields mentioned in the post above are in place. But we are facing the same issue.